# Azure Container App with public environment - how to define static FQDN URL

Tags: azure, fqdn, azure-container-apps

I can't quite find anything comprehensive on this subject so will try my luck with the community.

I have a working Azure Container App working. All working fine, container is being deployed and rolled out just fine with Single Revision Mode.

Every CD pipeline run generates and applies new revision which replaces previous app revisions, which is the correct behavior.

Every revision gets its own unique FQDN URL which is referenced as Revision URL, and looks similar to this:

```
my-container-app-name-revision-tag.some-container-descriptor.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io
```

Container App also seems to have a public ip address assigned to it by Azure.

Now, for the life of me i am unable to figure out a way to setup a static FQDN URL that will be usable across revision change - i.e. the same URL i could use regardless which revision is actively deployed. Would this even be possible in Azure Container App environment?

something in the order of: `my-container-app-name.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io`

I have ingress http traffic enabled for all networks and with dynamic revision-specific URLs  it works just fine.

[image]

Comment: Just replace the revision name with the container app name. If you click on `Overview` which is in the top left of the screen shot you have, it should be under `Application Url`.

Comment: thanks a lot! somehow this was not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: @ahmelsayed The application URL still contains a random part, which the OP denotes as  `some-container-descriptor`. In my case, for example, it is "orangebeach-8999d26d". WTH is "orange beach" and why it is in my URL? Can I change it?...

Comment: that's the unique name of your "app environment". You can change it if you have your own domain through the custom environment domain feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/environment-custom-dns-suffix